# Interesting problems that can be solved with algorithms

Tags: algorithm-analysis

I need to write a blog post on a problem that can be solved algorithmically. I need to do two things:

1) I need to decide what the naive brute force method would be and touch on it's time and Space complexities.

2) I need to come up with a more elegant/ideal method to solve the problem, then discuss tradeoffs with the ideal method's time and space big O

Does anyone have ideas for an interesting topic I can cover? I'm not looking for the answers, just the topic to cover

Here is an example of something I could write about: https://medium.com/@hannahsquier/two-algorithms-for-solving-vigneres-cipher-in-ruby-77bf0b37507a#.go43z5vas

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! Unfortunately, your question is not a good fit for the Stack Exchange format. We prefer questions that have objectively correct answers that will be useful both to the asker and others who have the same question in the future. What is or is not a suitable topic for study, projects or research is very much a matter of opinion and depends crucially on the interests and skills of the person who will be doing the work and the support that will be available to them. This is a question that you should be asking your professors.

Comment: Pick anything that interests *you*.

Comment: @Raphael I don't have professors, and I think this is a perfectly valid question. The answer range is certainly broad, but there are clearly defined parameters for validity.  I was just trying to collect interesting topics from the great minds of stack overflow that meet the above criteria

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the level of sophistication of your intended audience, a simple canonical example is testing whether an input number $n$ is prime.

A brute force approach is to test, for all $d$ in the range $2,\dotsc n-1$ whether $d$ divides $n$. If you find a $d$ that divides $n$ you can stop and assert that $n$ isn't prime; if you don't find any such $d$, you can assert that $n$ is prime. That'll take about $n$ divisions if $n$ is prime.

An improvement is to try just those $d\le\sqrt{n}$ (rounding up), since it's easy to see that if $n$ has any divisors, there must be one in that range. This is a big improvement, since it reduces the number of divisions from $n$ to $\sqrt{n}$, more or less.

If you want to expand this, there are even faster ways to test for primality and if your audience is sophisticated enough, you might want to try one or more of them.